# Node.js app doesn't work when I try to host it via GCP deploy command. Error: Cannot find module 'express'

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, npm, google-cloud-platform

I have my NodeJS app wrote using TypeScript and based on the Express framework. I want to host it in GCP cloud with `gcloud app deploy` command.
So, first of all, I build my TS sources to JavaScript -is that the correct way of doing it?.

Then from the `build` (with JS source code) folder I'm trying to run `npm start` command and it works successfully and I'm also able to check it with Preview:

[image].

It works well. So far, so good.

Then I run `gcloud app deploy` from the `build` folder (with built to JS sources) and I didn't see any errors during deploy.

But afterward, I receive a 500 error on each request whenever I'm trying to reach the deployed app. I've taken a look into a log and I see next error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'express'
```

**What seems to be the problem?**

I tried the next commands in the `build` folder:

```
    npm install
    npm install express --save
    npm install -g express
    sudo apt-get install node-express
```

Nothing works for me.

Here is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "full-node",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "dev": "node -r ts-node/register ./src/server.ts",
    "debug": "ts-node --inspect ./src/server.ts",
    "start": "node build/server.js",
    "prod": "npm run build && npm run start"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-node": "^7.0.1",
    "typescript": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.116",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "connect": "^3.6.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "firebase-admin": "^6.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10"
  }
}
```

Any idea what I'm missed? Is this the correct way to deploy an app wrote with TypeScript to GCP cloud?

**`app.yaml`:**

```
# [START app_yaml]
runtime: nodejs8
# [END app_yaml]
```

Comment: Can you share your `app.yml` that shows what you asked to deploy? Also, you may be able to run typescript directly on your server with `ts-node` without the need for compiling to JS

Comment: @ClémentPrévost sure, I've added `app.yaml` file. Yes, I can use `ts-node`, but seems like gcloud provide me a good tool out of the box with a good scalability. That's why I trying to make it works

Comment: what is your build output? or are you building locally and then deploying?

Comment: Have you tried using express typings https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/express?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was pretty simple. Seems like `gcloud app deploy` use `npm run build & npm run start` commands to start application somewhere inside. To host Node.Js wrote on TS first we need to build it to simple JS using `tsc` command. Then in the `build` folder rewrite `package.json` file to use correct commands. Look at my start command: `"start": "node build/server.js"`. I was using it inside `build` folder as well so that's mean `gcloud` command was searching in `/build/build/` folder. I've changed `start` command to `"start": "node server.js"` and then all works well.

Comment: i'm getting ´tsc: not found´ message

Answer (score 0):

since you are running gcloud app deploy from within the build folder,probably the package.json is not deployed as  npm install is run first by app engine  there is no way express could be missing.you can go to gcp console and under app engine view the version and then under diagnose you can view the source(the files that were actually deployed to app engine).keep in mind that this is only possible for the standard version and not the flex.I can see from your app.yaml you are using the standard.If some files are missing then go to your app root directory and in your .gcloudignore file you can ignore the files/folders you do not want to deploy.then run gcloud app deploy from within the root directory of your project